# How define json header in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show response in `json` format in controller and don't want to move in view. So, please let me any way so that I can show `json` response.

Here is the code where i want to add `json` headers.

```
$result = $this->mod_doc->get_list();   
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just give these a try.

```
public function signin() {
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);    

//add the header here
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $arr );
}
```

or Try this way

```
return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(200) // Return status
        ->set_output(json_encode(array(your array)));
```

Comment: only 

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

worked for me

Comment: There is no need to change the header status to 500, this can be excluded `set_status_header(500)`

Comment: The second one is way much better than writing header eachtime Works smoothly

Answer (score 6):

```
$result = $this->mod_doc->get_list();
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json') //set Json header
    ->set_output(json_encode($result));// make output json encoded
```

for more reference https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html?highlight=_output

```
$response = array('status' => 'OK');

$this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
        ->_display();
exit;
```